# Unusual Storage File Path

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My app has some basic FileProvider functionality for content. It works for the most part. However, I've gotten a strange error like this:

IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/4372-A61C/App/App-745405753.jpg

Basically the file path doesn't match our root path. When I attempt to recreate that image in the same way the path is:

/storage/emulated/0/App/App-283194903.jpg

basically what is this bit here? **4372-A61C**

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/App/App-283194903.jpg`. That is a completely different path which is not on your SD card but in external memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /storage/4372-A61C/App/App-745405753.jpg
```

That is a path of a file on a removable micro SD card.

You cannot use FileProvider to serve such files.

Better implement your own derived class of ContentProvider as then you can.

Comment: Ah SD card.... that makes a lot of sense. Could you explain a bit more whath you mean extending ContentProvider?

Comment: You should google for a CommonsWare blog where you find an example.